# how to compare to previous item in `each` iterator?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

**update**: sorry, I fixed my program:

```
a = [ 'str1' , 'str2', 'str2', 'str3'  ]
name = ''
a.each_with_index do |x, i |
  if x == name
    puts "#{x} found duplicate."
  else 
    puts x
    name = x  if i!= 0 
  end
end



     output: 
str1
str2
str2 found duplicate.
str3
```

Is there another beautiful way in `ruby` language to do the same thing ?

btw, actually. `a` is a `ActiveRecord::Relation` in my real case.

Thanks.

Comment: try to explain with words the intent, the code seems buggy (particularly that `x[i-1]` makes no sense). The best way: give some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Did each_cons still suitable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem you might have with `each_cons` is that it iterates through `n-1` pairs (if the length of the Enumerable is `n`). In some cases this means you have to separately handle edge cases for the first (or last) element.

In that case, it's really easy to implement a [method](http://jablan.radioni.ca/post/2175717120/each-with-previous-in-ruby) similar to `each_cons`, but which would yield `(nil, elem0)` for the first element (as opposed to `each_cons`, which yields `(elem0, elem1)`:

```
module Enumerable
  def each_with_previous
    self.inject(nil){|prev, curr| yield prev, curr; curr}
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15):

you can use [each_cons](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons):

```
irb(main):014:0> [1,2,3,4,5].each_cons(2) {|a,b| p "#{a} = #{b}"}
"1 = 2"
"2 = 3"
"3 = 4"
"4 = 5"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `each_cons`

```
a.each_cons(2) do |first,last|
  if last == name
    puts 'got you!'
  else
    name = first
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
a = [ 'str1' , 'str2', 'str3' , ..... ]
name = ''
a.each_cons(2) do |x, y|
  if y == name
     puts 'got you! '
  else 
     name = x
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As you probably want to do more than `puts` with the duplicates, I would rather keep the duplicates in a structure:

```
 ### question's example:
 a = [ 'str1' , 'str2', 'str2', 'str3'  ]
 #  => ["str1", "str2", "str2", "str3"] 
 a.each_cons(2).select{|a, b| a == b }.map{|m| m.first}
 #  => ["str2"] 
 ### a more complex example:
 d = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6]
 # => [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6] 
 d.each_cons(2).select{|a, b| a == b }.map{|m| m.first}
 #  => [3, 6]
```

More on at: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/192355 (cool answer of David A. Black)