# Rails core module extension not loading when RAILS_ENV=production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines, activesupport

***In Rails 3.2.12***, I am trying to add a method to the core [Enumerable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html) module as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517153/how-to-compare-to-previous-item-in-each-iterator/9520604#9520604), and I am using [require_dependency](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency) and [config.watchable_dirs](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Railtie/Configuration/watchable_dirs) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018757/rails3-not-reloading-code-in-lib-while-in-development-mode/10316566#10316566). My method works fine in development server and console, but when I `rake assets:precompile` or attempt to deploy I get `No such file to load -- lib/extensions/enumerable`. What piece am I missing to appropriately autoload this method from my lib directory?

***config/application.rb***

```
...
module Myapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.watchable_dirs['lib/extensions'] = [:rb]
  end
end
...
```

***lib/extensions/enumerable.rb***

```
module Enumerable
  def each_with_previous
    self.inject(nil){|prev, curr| yield prev, curr; curr}
    self
  end
end
```

***app/models/mymodel.rb***

```
class Mymodel
  ...
  require_dependency 'lib/extensions/enumerable.rb'
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `lib` in your `require_dependency` is extraneous:

```
require_dependency 'extensions/enumerable.rb'
```